# Python not exporting to csv from dictionary

Tags: python, csv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to export a dictionary of lists, each list containing data, into a csv file, however python doesn't output anything to this file. I'm a novice python user but it seems that python isn't even 'activating' a csv since, before when I've outputted to a csv file, one has been created automatically if one doesn't exist with the specified name. This  is not the case in this instance.  I thought it might be the data I was exporting but even with random data, the code fails. Oddly enough the exact same code seemed to work in isolation when I put it in a file on its own and ran it with the same test data.

```
def export_to_csv(all_rows_dict):
    with open('twtts_depth.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for i in range(10):
        writer.writerow(["hey","ho","hey", "ho"])
```

I am also running PIL but I wouldn't imagine this would affect it. The data originally was taken from an image.

The whole code (with actual data, not test data) is:

```
import csv
from PIL import Image

def get_data():
    #open image with reference colurs
    ref_img = Image.open("colour_pallate.png")
    ref_pixels_lst = list(ref_img.getdata())
    #open image being analysed
    colour_img = Image.open("contour_map_NEW_small.png")
    colour_pixels_lst = list(colour_img.getdata())
    colour_width, colour_height = colour_img.size
    grid_img = Image.open("grid_for_contour_NEW_small.png")
    grid_pixels_lst = list(grid_img.getdata())
    return ref_pixels_lst, colour_width, colour_height, colour_pixels_lst, grid_pixels_lst
    #get data for colour information

    def find_gridpoints(colour_pixels_lst, grid_pixels_lst):
        gridpoints_lst = []
        for i in range(len(grid_pixels_lst)):
            if grid_pixels_lst[i] != (255,255,255):
                gridpoints_lst.append(i)
        print(gridpoints_lst[1:10])
        return gridpoints_lst

    def find_colour_points(gridpoints_lst, colour_pixels_lst, ref_pixels_lst):
        grid_heights_lst = []
        for i in  range(len(gridpoints_lst)):
            colour = colour_pixels_lst[gridpoints_lst[i]]
            for j in range(len(ref_pixels_lst)):
                if ref_pixels_lst[j] == colour:
                    depth = (len(ref_pixels_lst) - (j+1))*15
                    grid_heights_lst.append(depth)
        return grid_heights_lst

    def split_list_to_rows(colour_width, colour_height, grid_pixels_lst):
        flag = False;
        counter = 0
        gridpoints_per_row = 0
        while gridpoints_per_row == 0:
            for i in range(colour_width):
                if grid_pixels_lst[(colour_width*counter) + i] != (255,255,255):
                    gridpoints_per_row += 1
            counter += 1
        no_of_rows = int(how_many_points(grid_pixels_lst) / gridpoints_per_row)
        return gridpoints_per_row, no_of_rows

    def how_many_points(grid_pixels_lst):
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(grid_pixels_lst)):
            if grid_pixels_lst[i] != (255,255,255):
                counter += 1
        print(counter)
        return counter

    def create_dictionary_rows(grid_heights_lst, gridpoints_per_row, no_of_rows):
        all_rows_dict = {}
        for i in range(no_of_rows):
            all_rows_dict['row_{}'.format(i+1)] = []
            for j in range(gridpoints_per_row):
                all_rows_dict['row_{}'.format(i+1)].append(grid_heights_lst[(gridpoints_per_row*i)+j])
        return all_rows_dict


    def export_to_csv(all_rows_dict):
        with open('output_depths.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for i in range(len(all_rows_dict)):
                writer.writerow(all_rows_dict['row_{}'.format(i+1)])

ref_pixels_lst, colour_width, colour_height, colour_pixels_lst, grid_pixels_lst = get_data()

gridpoints_lst = find_gridpoints(colour_pixels_lst, grid_pixels_lst)

grid_heights_lst = find_colour_points(gridpoints_lst, colour_pixels_lst, ref_pixels_lst)

gridpoints_per_row, no_of_rows = split_list_to_rows(colour_width, colour_height, grid_pixels_lst)

all_rows_dict = create_dictionary_rows(grid_heights_lst, gridpoints_per_row, no_of_rows)

export_to_csv(all_rows_dict)
```

Comment: You are writing to a *relative path*. Where that file ends up depends on the programs current working directory; use `print(os.getcwd())` to see where that might be. Use an absolute path if you want to make sure of where it is going to be written to.

Comment: I'll try it out, but I've always used a relative path for csv stuff and have never had an issue with it before. Running the export code in the exact same directory, just isolated on its own seemed to work.

Comment: The current working directory depends on where you started the script from. If in a terminal or console, that'll be the working directory of the prompt from which you started Python. When using a GUI launcher (doubleclicking, or using an IDE) the working directory can be anywhere, it depends on the parent process.

Comment: Had, a check, the output directory is the same as the python file. So as far as I'm aware, if successful, this is where the end csv should appear?

Comment: So, continue debugging. Put print statements in the function to ensure it is being run. Use an absolute path, say `/tmp/test.csv`. Try it in the console to see what happens, etc.